# How to replace the default namespace of an Xml document using Xslt

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm new on xslt, I've received a simple request: Replace the default xml namespace by another one in an xml document using Xslt (1.0, I can't use 2.0).

I find an easy way of doing it but I've still have a bug I don't understand (Wich happens with XslCompiledTransform from .Net framework 4.5 and with Altova Xml Spy but not with the Xslt plugin from Notepad++ for example):

**This is the input Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:old.namespace">
    <Companies>
        <Company>
            <AuditedOn xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
                <d4p1:DateTime>2012-10-08T13:34:04.04Z</d4p1:DateTime>
                <d4p1:OffsetMinutes>0</d4p1:OffsetMinutes>
            </AuditedOn>
            <Name>CompanyNameTest</Name>
        </Company>
        <Company>
            <AuditedOn xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
                <d6p1:DateTime>2012-10-08T13:34:04.04Z</d6p1:DateTime>
                <d6p1:OffsetMinutes>0</d6p1:OffsetMinutes>
            </AuditedOn>
            <Name>CompanyNameTest2</Name>
        </Company>
    </Companies>
</Test>
```

**My Xslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:previous="urn:old.namespace" >

   <xsl:output encoding='UTF-8' indent='yes' method='xml'/>

  <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Previous namespace -> current. No other changes required. -->
  <xsl:template match='previous:*'>
    <xsl:element name='{local-name()}'
                 namespace='urn:new.namespace'>
      <xsl:copy-of select='namespace::*[not(. = namespace-uri(current()))]' />
      <xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()' />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**And the result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns="urn:new.namespace" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Companies>
        <Company>
            <AuditedOn xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
                <d4p1:DateTime xmlns="urn:old.namespace">2012-10-08T13:34:04.04Z</d4p1:DateTime>
                <d4p1:OffsetMinutes xmlns="urn:old.namespace">0</d4p1:OffsetMinutes>
            </AuditedOn>
            <Name>CompanyNameTest</Name>
        </Company>
        <Company>
            <AuditedOn xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
                <d6p1:DateTime xmlns="urn:old.namespace">2012-10-08T13:34:04.04Z</d6p1:DateTime>
                <d6p1:OffsetMinutes xmlns="urn:old.namespace">0</d6p1:OffsetMinutes>
            </AuditedOn>
            <Name>CompanyNameTest2</Name>
        </Company>
    </Companies>
</Test>
```

As you can see, on the AuditedOn node (Which is a DateTimeOffset object), the transformation set again xmlns="urn:old.namespace" on every node. I don't understand why.

**UPDATE**:

So, my expected result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns="urn:new.namespace" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Companies>
    <Company>
        <AuditedOn xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
            <d4p1:DateTime>2012-10-08T13:34:04.04Z</d4p1:DateTime>
            <d4p1:OffsetMinutes>0</d4p1:OffsetMinutes>
        </AuditedOn>
        <Name>CompanyNameTest</Name>
    </Company>
    <Company>
        <AuditedOn xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
            <d6p1:DateTime>2012-10-08T13:34:04.04Z</d6p1:DateTime>
            <d6p1:OffsetMinutes>0</d6p1:OffsetMinutes>
        </AuditedOn>
        <Name>CompanyNameTest2</Name>
    </Company>
</Companies>
</Test>
```

Please, can someone help me?

Comment: You are copying in-scope namespaces with `<xsl:copy>`, you would need to replace that with `<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">`, however that way for instance the `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` would be lost.

Comment: What is the result that you're after?

Comment: I don't want the urn:old.namespace set as a default namespace on de DateTime and OffsetMinutes nodes.

Comment: Why use XSLT for this? You could easily just change the content of the `xmlns=".."` declaration using simple string manipulation.

Comment: You're right, that's what I've said. The Xslt is a part of the application requirements, they can put them in a folder to dynamically change the output of an SOA app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will produce the result you're looking for (which you neglected to provide):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:previous="urn:old.namespace">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- old namespace -> new -->
<xsl:template match="previous:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:new.namespace">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = 'urn:old.namespace')]" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- instead of identity transform template -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns="urn:new.namespace" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Companies>
      <Company>
         <AuditedOn xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
            <d4p1:DateTime>2012-10-08T13:34:04.04Z</d4p1:DateTime>
            <d4p1:OffsetMinutes>0</d4p1:OffsetMinutes>
         </AuditedOn>
         <Name>CompanyNameTest</Name>
      </Company>
      <Company>
         <AuditedOn xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
            <d6p1:DateTime>2012-10-08T13:34:04.04Z</d6p1:DateTime>
            <d6p1:OffsetMinutes>0</d6p1:OffsetMinutes>
         </AuditedOn>
         <Name>CompanyNameTest2</Name>
      </Company>
   </Companies>
</Test>
```

---

### Added note:

The above could be simplified to just:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- old namespace -> new -->
<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri() = 'urn:old.namespace']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="urn:new.namespace">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result here would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Test xmlns="urn:new.namespace">
   <Companies>
      <Company>
         <AuditedOn>
            <d4p1:DateTime xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:old.namespace">2012-10-08T13:34:04.04Z</d4p1:DateTime>
            <d4p1:OffsetMinutes xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:old.namespace">0</d4p1:OffsetMinutes>
         </AuditedOn>
         <Name>CompanyNameTest</Name>
      </Company>
      <Company>
         <AuditedOn>
            <d6p1:DateTime xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:old.namespace">2012-10-08T13:34:04.04Z</d6p1:DateTime>
            <d6p1:OffsetMinutes xmlns:d6p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:old.namespace">0</d6p1:OffsetMinutes>
         </AuditedOn>
         <Name>CompanyNameTest2</Name>
      </Company>
   </Companies>
</Test>
```

**This result is semantically the same as the other one.** The differences are merely cosmetic:

- The namespace declaration
  `xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` has been moved
  and (needlessly) replicated to other elements - however, this
  declaration is redundant anyway, so it doesn't matter where it
  appears, or if appears at all;
- Some elements declare a default namespace as
  `xmlns="urn:old.namespace"` - however, **no element is actually
  placed in this namespace**.

Similarly, **the result you have reported in the question is also semantically identical to the two above**. The redundant default namespace declaration of `xmlns="urn:old.namespace"` are just that: redundant. No node in the entire result is actually placed in this namespace.

Any target application that parses the result with a standard-conformant XML parser should not be able to tell the differences between these three results.

Comment: The first solution you provide seems better to me: We avoid to add unused old namespace (xmlns="urn:old.namespace") to nodes and we keep the other namespaces on the root node (I put de xmlns:i as a test, my exemple is just a dummy exemple from a greater xml with a lot of namespaces)

Comment: You're right. I apologize about that, I tried to be clear but I've lost some of my requirements by doing it.